# Unknown bad value error in Ruby Script

Tags: ruby, rubygems, runtime-error

I'm encountering an error with this associated Ruby script at [this page](https://gist.github.com/joshwand/5402126)

I receive the error

`'<main>': bad value for range <ArgumentError>`

I am unsure if I might have insufficient dependencies or if there's other notable error here.

The only other helpful information I can provide is that I'm a Windows user, that I've installed the asked-of dependencies and the the list of Ruby gems installed

`bigdecimal (1.1.0)
domain_name (0.5.16)
faraday (0.8.9)
faraday_middleware (0.9.0)
http-cookie (1.0.2)
io-console (0.3)
json (1.5.5)
mechanize (2.7.3)
mime-types (2.1)
mini_portile (0.5.2)
minitest (2.5.1)
multipart-post (2.0.0, 1.2.0)
net-http-digest_auth (1.4)
net-http-persistent (2.9.4)
nokogiri (1.6.1 x86-mingw32)
ntlm-http (0.1.1)
oauth (0.4.7)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.9.5)
simple_oauth (0.2.0)
tumblr_client (0.8.2)
unf (0.1.3)
unf_ext (0.0.6 x86-mingw32)
webrobots (0.1.1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try doing

```
liked_count = likes["liked_count"].to_i
```

on line no [26](https://gist.github.com/joshwand/5402126#file-tumblr-likes-downloader-rb-L26)